# Retrieving gene matrix from internet in GSEA desktop

Tags: rna-seq, gsea

This error appeared to me, and I have the program connected to the internet. I already installed java 8, but it still doesn't get me the gene set databases.
[image]

Comment: Did you hit the "Help" button at the bottom?

Comment: Yes i did, but it didn't help

Comment: Which version of the software are you using? Did you check your connection ?  Why do you need an online "Gene Matrix" dataset? Aren't  you trying to analyze your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked firewall settings on your laptop?

See **Firewall / FTP connection issues** at:

[GSEA wiki - known issues](http://software.broadinstitute.org/cancer/software/gsea/wiki/index.php/Known_Issues)